# Configuration for spark job to write 3000000 file as output

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have to generate 3000000 files as the output of spark job.

I have two input file :

```
File 1 -> Size=3.3 Compressed, No.Of Records=13979835
File 2 -> Size=1.g Compressed, No.Of Records=6170229
```

Spark Job is doing the following:

1. reading both this file and joining them based on common column1. -> DataFrame-A
2. Grouping result of DataFrame-A based on one column2 -> DataFrame-B
3. From DataFrame-B used array_join for the aggregated column and separate that column by '\n' char. -> DataFrame-C
4. Writing result of DataFrame-C partition by column2.

   ```
   val DF1 = sparkSession.read.json("FILE1") //    |ID     |isHighway|isRamp|pvId      |linkIdx|ffs |length            |
   val DF12 = sparkSession.read.json("FILE2") //    |lId    |pid       |

   val joinExpression = DF1.col("pvId") === DF2.col("lId")
   val DFA = DF.join(tpLinkDF, joinExpression, "inner").select(col("ID").as("SCAR"), col("lId"), col("length"), col("ffs"), col("ar"), col("pid")).orderBy("linkIdx")
   val DFB = DFA.select(col("SCAR"),concat_ws(",", col("lId"), col("length"),col("ffs"), col("ar"), col("pid")).as("links")).groupBy("SCAR").agg(collect_list("links").as("links"))

   val DFC = DFB.select(col("SCAR"), array_join(col("links"), "\n").as("links"))
   DFC.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("quote", "\u0000").partitionBy("SCAR").mode(SaveMode.Append).format("csv").save("/tmp")
   ```

I have to generate 3000000 files as output of spark job.

Comment: Why is this required? Small files issue.

Comment: it is kind of requirement where other system need to read these small files (not all but as request arrive for that file each file contain some id in file name so request with that ID for that file received system has to read that file ) and give result in realtime within 45 sec.

Comment: Sounds like a disaster in all honesty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running some test I got an idea to run this job in batch like :

- query startIdx: 0, endIndex:100000
- query startIdx: 100000, endIndex:200000
- query startIdx: 200000, endIndex:300000

and so.... on till

- query startIdx: 2900000, endIndex:3000000